# Add www-data to alternate group

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, users

I am working with two users: me and www-data.  Each user has their own group by default.  I want to be able to easily grant read, write, and/or execute permissions to both users, without giving the permissions to the public.

My understanding of the Linux file permissions system is that if I have the following file:

```
test.php me:me 770
```

and the group me contains the users me and www-data, then both users would have full permissions for the file test.php. This is not working, however.  I have added the user www-data to the group me and set the permissions to 770, but Apache says permissions are denied.  If I change the file group to www-data so that it looks like

```
test.php me:www-data 770
```

the file loads fine.  The problem is that I upload the files over ftp under the user me.  It's easy to change the group, but it gets incredibly tedious if I have to SSH into the server every time I upload a new file to change the group.  My understanding is that groups exist just for circumstances like these, but I don't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the group of all files/directories to **www-data** then enable setgid:

```
sudo chmod -R g+s /path/to/www/directory/
```

All files and directories will be created with **www-data** group from now on.